# Combinations from a finite pool of objects

Tags: probability, combinatorics, arithmetic, factorial

We've got a pool containing 5 A-balls, 4 B-balls, 3 C-balls, 2 D-balls and one E-ball. How many ways are there to pull out 5 balls?

I thought of dividing off from the formula: $\frac{15!}{10!}$ but the issue is that we don't know which balls in each sampling will be identical.

Is there a nice combinatorial method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the coefficient of $x^5$ in $(1+x)(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)$, which is $\boxed{71}$ by [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2bx%29%281%2bx%2bx%5E2%29%281%2bx%2bx%5E2%2bx%5E3%29%281%2bx%2bx%5E2%2bx%5E3%2bx%5E4%29%281%2bx%2bx%5E2%2bx%5E3%2bx%5E4%2bx%5E5%29).

Indeed, you can see that to get $x^5$ we need to choose some power from every parenthesis, and each of them corresponds to one of the jars.